# Is "false concedence" a thing? If not, is there an established term?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

```
concedence /kənˈsiːd(ə)ns/

noun
    1) The action of conceding; concession, agreement.
```

Here's what I describe as *false* concedence:

> Expressing that you concede a less consequential point, but only in an effort to show that you are willing to concede points. Your unspoken belief is that you do not concede that point. However if pressured, you are willing to forfeit that belief in order to maintain the perception had always conceded the point.

Is there a name for this sort of action? Technically a lie if unchallenged. But when challenged, the speaker may decide it's inconsequential and change their actions to make it the truth.

Comment: almost white lie but not quite https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/white%20lie

Comment: I see nothing wrong with conceding something for the sake of an *argument*. It doesn't necessarily mean that you agree with the point—merely that you agree to no longer *dispute* it. There's a difference. I've heard *I don't agree, but I'll concede the point (for now).*

Comment: @JasonBassford I guess I'm referring to the "agreement" definition of concede. As in saying "yeah you're right" but thinking "they're not actually right".

Comment: If somebody says means *yes, you're right* when they use the word *concede*, but they don't actually believe the person is right, then they are being deceptive or dishonest—or they are lying (depending on how you look at it). But that doesn't really have anything to do with the word *concede* itself—because any synonymous word for that one sense of the word could be used.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom **agree to differ (disagree)** may fit this question:  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/agree+to+differ)

> Of two parties, to mutually accept that they simply do not (and will
>   not) share the same view on a particular issue, in the interest of
>   moving past the issue or avoiding further confrontation.

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4146?redirectedFrom=agree%20to%20differ#eid241002315) cites this 1699 usage:

> 1699   R. Ferguson Just & Modest Vindic. Scots Design 202   If
>   we agree to differ in Religious Matters of less Importance, we might
>   thereupon possibly better accord.

Comment: Not quite, I believe. In my scenario, both parties agree to *agree*, even though in truth one party does not. They do not end the subject saying they disagree - one party opts to say they agree, which would be a lie.

Comment: +1 Yes, that's what I was getting at in my comment under the question. When you concede a point of an argument, that doesn't mean that you are agreeing with the point itself—simply that you are moving on.

Answer (score 0):

*Conceding* (*concession*) might only mean you are ceasing to pursue the argument, as opposed to having been convinced.  One might concede for tactical reasons, as you explained.  Here's a way to express that:

**face-saving solution**

Example:

> We met with the deputy superintendent.  After two hours, we arrived at a face-saving solution: we would present a lease for an address in another school's catchment area.  The district would transfer the student to the other school mid-year, omitting the usual proof of residence requirements.  For our part, in exchange for a reprieve from the teacher bullying, and a fresh start in another school, we would not file a state complaint.

Explanation: the district did not have to admit any fault, and we wouldn't have to actually move.  The administrator explicitly told us he didn't care where we did our laundry, or even where we slept at night.

Here is [Cambridge's definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/face-saving):

> done so that other people will continue to respect you: *a face-saving exercise/gesture*